# Why can't I update the firmware on my Nikon Coolpix?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, firmware, coolpix

I'm trying to update the firmware on a Nikon Coolpix B500.  I'm using a new memory card.  I have tried formatting the card in the camera first.  Then I put the downloaded folder on the card.  I've also tried just putting the .bin part on the card.  The camera does not ask whether we want to update or not. I've also erased the memory card and started over just putting the file on the card and then into the camera. Still doesn't ask if we want to update. I'm using a Mac. I've checked the card using disk utility, and it says it is a FAT file. Not sure what else to try. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using the camera's menu to tell it to update the firmware? Or are you naively expecting it to happen automatically when the camera is turned on with the card containing the correct file inserted?

Answer (score 1):

[According to the Nikon instructions](https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/download/fw/333.html), after putting the firmware folder (created when you installed the downloaded dmg file) onto the memory card and turned the camera on-

> Select Firmware version in the Set up menu and follow the on-screen instructions to complete the firmware update.

You don't include this step in your description...

Comment: [This](https://crossgate.nikonimglib.com/dsd_redirect/redirect.do?P=9SYQu32&R=pQhGA47&L=cWq3c02&O=3eQZt00) is a more comprehensive 'howto' for upgrading your firmware...

Comment: This is different from many cameras where simply turning on the camera with the firmware binary on the card, so easily overlooked!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently my Coolpix B500 version 1.1 firmware has the same hitch.  When I go to the firmware version menu pick all i get is the display of the version 1.1 with no other menu options. the reader needs to understand that we do not get any picks under firmware version menu only the version installed.  Other than the simple fact that the update does not conform to the instructions which halts any possible update it works perfectly.